# Fail to install pyjags

Tags: python, python-2.7, jags

My python version is `2.7`. I tried to install `pyjags` using `pip install pyjags` but got such error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/dh/cyj9qhyj271945lvydyv5yr80000gn/T/pip-build-yuHm33/pyjags/setup.py", line 68, in <module>
        add_jags(ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/dh/cyj9qhyj271945lvydyv5yr80000gn/T/pip-build-yuHm33/pyjags/setup.py", line 46, in add_jags
        version = add_pkg_config(ext, 'jags')
      File "/private/var/folders/dh/cyj9qhyj271945lvydyv5yr80000gn/T/pip-build-yuHm33/pyjags/setup.py", line 34, in add_pkg_config
        output = subprocess.check_output(args)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
        process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/dh/cyj9qhyj271945lvydyv5yr80000gn/T/pip-build-yuHm33/pyjags
```

Comment: @Gokul_uf mac os 10.10

Comment: Try updating `pip` usiing `pip install --upgrade pip` and trying again

Comment: @Gokul_uf `already up-to-date`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just deployed a python package and had same errors when I tried to install via `pip`. Turns out the main reasons was that the project artifacts (static files, etc) were not included in the MANIFEST file or it couldn't load a file path. I think you might want to consult the documentation [here](https://pyjags.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html).

The line below was copied from the docs:

The setup.py script uses **pkg-config** to locate the JAGS library. If JAGS is installed in some non-standard location, then you may need to configure pkg-config to pick up correct metadata file. For example, if JAGS have been configured with --prefix=/opt/, then JAGS metadata file would be located in /opt/lib/pkgconfig/. This path can be included in pkg-config search path as follows:

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH

From your track trace, it seems like you failed to configure that.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is not a supported installation method. Read the installation instructions on the website [enter link description here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/).

Comment: What do you mean? I can't install with `pip`?